# How to solve the "IWAB0014E Unexpected exception occurred" Error in eclipse 2023.03

Tags: java, spring, eclipse, soap, apache-axis

How to solve the "IWAB0014E Unexpected exception occurred" Error in eclipse 2023.03.

Running:
Server : Apache Tomcat v9.0
JRE : JavaSE 17

```
IWAB0014E Unexpected exception occurred.
  com/ibm/icu/util/StringTokenizer
      java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/ibm/icu/util/StringTokenizer
      at org.eclipse.jst.ws.internal.consumption.common.FacetUtils.greaterThan(FacetUtils.java:1279)
      at org.eclipse.jst.ws.internal.consumption.common.FacetUtils.getRuntimes(FacetUtils.java:1153)
      at org.eclipse.jst.ws.internal.consumption.ui.wsrt.WebServiceRuntimeExtensionUtils2.getRuntimes(WebServiceRuntimeExtensionUtils2.java:2329)
      at org.eclipse.jst.ws.internal.consumption.ui.wsrt.WebServiceRuntimeExtensionUtils2.getServerFactoryIdsByServiceRuntime(WebServiceRuntimeExtensionUtils2.java:732)
      at org.eclipse.jst.ws.internal.consumption.ui.wsrt.WebServiceRuntimeExtensionUtils2.getServerFactoryIdsByServiceType(WebServiceRuntimeExtensionUtils2.java:671)
      at org.eclipse.jst.ws.internal.consumption.ui.wsrt.WebServiceRuntimeExtensionUtils2.getDefaultServerValueFor(WebServiceRuntimeExtensionUtils2.java:896)
      at org.eclipse.jst.ws.internal.creation.ui.widgets.ServerWizardWidgetDefaultingCommand.execute(ServerWizardWidgetDefaultingCommand.java:53)
      at org.eclipse.wst.command.internal.env.core.fragment.CommandFragmentEngine.runCommand(CommandFragmentEngine.java:421)
      at org.eclipse.wst.command.internal.env.core.fragment.CommandFragmentEngine.visitTop(CommandFragmentEngine.java:361)
      at org.eclipse.wst.command.internal.env.core.fragment.CommandFragmentEngine.moveForwardToNextStop(CommandFragmentEngine.java:256)
      at org.eclipse.wst.command.internal.env.ui.widgets.SimpleCommandEngineManager$6.run(SimpleCommandEngineManager.java:296)
      at org.eclipse.wst.command.internal.env.ui.widgets.SimpleCommandEngineManager.runForwardToNextStop(SimpleCommandEngineManager.java:260)
      at org.eclipse.wst.command.internal.env.ui.widgets.WizardPageManager.runForwardToNextStop(WizardPageManager.java:93)
      at org.eclipse.wst.command.internal.env.ui.widgets.WizardPageManager.getNextPage(WizardPageManager.java:156)
      at org.eclipse.wst.command.internal.env.ui.widgets.WizardPageManager.getStartingPage(WizardPageManager.java:82)
      at org.eclipse.wst.command.internal.env.ui.widgets.DynamicWizard.getStartingPage(DynamicWizard.java:366)
      at org.eclipse.jface.wizard.WizardDialog.showStartingPage(WizardDialog.java:1265)
      at org.eclipse.jface.wizard.WizardDialog.createContents(WizardDialog.java:638)
      at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.create(Window.java:431)
      at org.eclipse.jface.dialogs.Dialog.create(Dialog.java:1094)
      at org.eclipse.wst.command.internal.env.ui.widgets.popup.DynamicPopupWizard.run(DynamicPopupWizard.java:128)
      at org.eclipse.ui.internal.PluginAction.runWithEvent(PluginAction.java:239)
      at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.handleWidgetSelection(ActionContributionItem.java:580)
      at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.lambda$4(ActionContributionItem.java:414)
      at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:89)
      at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Display.java:4256)
      at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1066)
      at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:4054)
      at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3642)
      at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$5.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1155)
      at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:338)
      at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1046)
      at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:155)
      at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.lambda$3(Workbench.java:643)
      at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:338)
      at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:550)
      at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:171)
      at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:152)
      at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:203)
      at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:136)
      at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:104)
      at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:402)
      at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:255)
      at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:104)
      at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:578)
      at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:659)
      at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:596)
      at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1467)
      at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1440)
      Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.ibm.icu.util.StringTokenizer cannot be found by org.eclipse.jst.ws.consumption_1.0.1600.v202302070757
      ... 49 more
```

Tried

- import javax.jws.WebService; however the javas.jws is not found.
- Right Clicking on the class "Web Service"-> "create Web service"

Comment: Please go to the _Error Log_ view, select the error, hit Ctrl+C and paste it into your question formatted as _Sample Code_. Is this a fresh installation of Eclipse 2023-03?

Answer (score 0):

Re-Installed eclipse
issue resolved